# Unity C# JSON Library without Exceptions

Tags: json, exception, unity-game-engine

My team is currently using Boomlagoon's JSON library. The problem is that we ship the game with "fast but no exceptions" turned on (like most recommend to do), so if there is a JSON error the app will crash. The JSON string we are deserializing is from a server, which is why it is not necessarily trustworthy. Simply wrapping JSONObject.Parse in a try/catch would actually by sufficient for our needs (it is fine to ignore a broken response, and all we care about is not CRASHING). However, since exceptions are turned off, this can no longer be relied upon. The only solution we can think of is to write a JSON-verifier (e.g. if (JSON.verify(string)) JSONObject.Parse(string) ), which starts to just look like writing our own JSON parse at that point. Is there an alternative strategy or perhaps a JSON library out there that uses error objects instead of exceptions?

Comment: If you're comfortable with a bare-bones implementation, [MiniJSON](https://gist.github.com/darktable/1411710) is easy to modify and returns null rather than throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not mistaken: http://james.newtonking.com/json would do the validating,
it is open source and written in c# wrap it in a plugin and throw in a plugin folder in unity and you will have a validator.